# How to filter a nested array of object by values and get root object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a json object as below:

```
[
  {
    name: 'data 1',
    users: [
      {
        username: 'user 1',
        full_name: 'name 1',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 1', name: 'source name 1' },
          { type: 'type 2', name: 'source name 2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        username: 'user 2',
        full_name: 'name 2',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 3', name: 'source name 3' },
          { type: 'type 4', name: 'source name 4' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'data 2',
    users: [
      { username: 'user 3', full_name: 'name 3' },
      {
        username: 'user 4',
        full_name: 'name 4',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 5', name: 'source name 3' },
          { type: 'type 6', name: 'source name 5' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'data 3',
    users: [
      { username: 'user 5', full_name: 'name 5' },
      {
        username: 'user 6',
        full_name: 'name 6',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 5', name: 'source name 6' },
          { type: 'type 6', name: 'source name 7' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need a function that filter data recursively by its all values.
For example when I type "data 1" it should return an array such as

```
[
  {
    name: 'data 1',
    users: [
      {
        username: 'user 1',
        full_name: 'name 1',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 1', name: 'source name 1' },
          { type: 'type 2', name: 'source name 2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        username: 'user 2',
        full_name: 'name 2',
        sources: [
          { type: 'type 3', name: 'source name 3' },
          { type: 'type 4', name: 'source name 4' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

or if I type "source name 3" it should return both "data 1" and "data 2" objects as an array.

The json object may have more arrays or objects in its values. I have tried something like this but it returns all data instead of filtered data.

```
function search(data) {
  return data.filter((data) => {
    Object.values(data).some((value) =>
      value.constructor.name === 'Array'
        ? search(value)
        : value.constructor.name === 'Object'
        ? Object.values(value).some((innerValue) =>
            innerValue.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
          )
        : value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
    );
  });
}
```

If I had to do that by some specific key it would be easy but I have to filter dynamically by all keys. What should I do to filter a json object like this?

Comment: So you're trying to get the all the objects `{name, users, ...}` that contains the object values specified?

Comment: yes exactly as you said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an recursive approach. By having an object it iterates the values as well.

```js
const
    has = value => object => Object
        .values(object)
        .some(v => v === value || v && typeof v === 'object' && has(value)(v)),
    filter = (array, value) => array.filter(has(value)),
    data = [{ name: 'data 1', users: [{ username: 'user 1', full_name: 'name 1', sources: [{ type: 'type 1', name: 'source name 1' }, { type: 'type 2', name: 'source name 2' }] }, { username: 'user 2', full_name: 'name 2', sources: [{ type: 'type 3', name: 'source name 3' }, { type: 'type 4', name: 'source name 4' }] }] }, { name: 'data 2', users: [{ username: 'user 3', full_name: 'name 3' }, { username: 'user 4', full_name: 'name 4', sources: [{ type: 'type 5', name: 'source name 3' }, { type: 'type 6', name: 'source name 5' }] }] }, { name: 'data 3', users: [{ username: 'user 5', full_name: 'name 5' }, { username: 'user 6', full_name: 'name 6', sources: [ { type: 'type 5', name: 'source name 6' }, { type: 'type 6', name: 'source name 7' }] }] }];

console.log(filter(data, 'data 1'));
console.log(filter(data, 'source name 3'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```